# How do I add a password field during registration?

Tags: 8, users

i am using Drupal 8. I want to set the password field and confirm password field during registration. On admin/configuration this option is not available. Is there a setting to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Disabling email confirmation. Which you probably don't want.

Drupal doesn't *really* have mail confirmation. It just doesn't tell the user his password, and then he gets a password recovery link and can provide a password after that.

I've built a custom module for this that allowed it for a project, you basically need to add a field to users, prevent login if that is not set, set it on the first login through password recovery. Change the user registration submission to send a confirmation mail anyway. And care about some special cases, like admin created users. Not trivial.

There are contrib modules for this, for example https://www.drupal.org/project/user_registrationpassword. there's no official release yet, but maybe someone started porting it.

Comment: This core issue will fix this, help appreciated: [Allow password on registration without disabling e-mail verification #115801](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/115801)